# Mensaje de mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, apache

Estaba intentando cargar contenido en una tabla HTML con los datos que tengo en la BD, pero me encuentro con este "pequeño" error. He estado visualizando diferentes sitios y como no encontré una solución rápida y funcional acudo a ustedes.

Este es mi codigo PHP.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])){
header("location:login.php");
}
include "conexion.php";
$correo = $_SESSION["user"];
$query = "SELECT cbtahd.tblreportes.emisor,cbtahd.tblempleados.sucursal,cbtahd.tblreportes.area,cbtahd.tblempleados.extension,cbtahd.tblreportes.extension ,cbtahd.tblreportes.reporte, cbtahd.tblreportes.fechaEmi FROM tblempleados inner join tblreportes on tblreportes.receptor = tblempleados.nombreapellidoarea where tblempleados.email = '$correo'";
$resultado = mysql_query($query);

while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado, $conexion) or die (mysql_error())){
echo "fila[emisor]";
}
?>
```

Este es el mensaje que me arroja el servidor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi archivo de conexion.php

```
<?php
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","","cbtahd");
?>
```

Y este es el select que puse en PHP corriendo directamente desde el workbench.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

En conexión.php estás utilizando `mysqli` y a la hora de hacer la consulta y obtener los resultados utilizas `mysql_query` y `mysql_fetch_array`. Tienes que adaptar esas funciones a la extensión `mysqli`

Answer (score 2):

El problema reside en que estás usando distintas funciones para realizar las consultas.

Por una parte conectas mediante la clase `mysqli` y continuas con las funciones de `mysql`.

Te pongo tres ejemplos *muy simples* de las funciones `mysql`, `mysqli` y la clase `mysqli`.

MySql (Obsoleta)

```
$conexion      = mysql_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'contraseña');
$baseDeDatos   = mysql_select_db('base_de_datos', $conexion);
$consulta      = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM usuarios');
$salidaDeDatos = mysql_fetch_array($consulta);
mysql_close($conexion);
```

MySqli

```
$conexion      = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'contraseña', 'base_de_datos');
$consulta      = mysqli_query($conexion, 'SELECT * FROM usuarios');
$salidaDeDatos = $consulta->fetch_array();
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Clase MySqli

```
$conexion      = new mysqli('localhost', 'usuario', 'contraseña', 'base_de_datos');
$consulta      = $conexion->query('SELECT * FROM usuarios');
$salidaDeDatos = $consulta->fetch_array();
$conexion->close();
```

Según la que elijas para funcionar, deberías mantener las funciones asociadas a cada tipo de conexión y así evitar errores.

Varían un poco la forma de operar con cada una. En la página oficial de PHP podrás encontrar todas las funciones que necesitas.

[MySql](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysql.php) y [MySqli](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php)