# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in

Tags: php

Realizo la conexion a la base de datos:

```
$db_host="localhost";
$db_nombre="prueba"; 
$db_user="root"; 
$db_pass=""; 

$link=mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
```

Ahora realizo la consulta:

```
$strQuery = "SELECT id, nombre FROM persona";
$resultado = mysql_query ($strQuery);
```

Cuando intento recorrer el ResulSet mediante **mysql_fetch_array:**

```
while($arreglo = mysql_fetch_array ($resultado)) {
    echo $arreglo ["nombre"];
}
```

Me lanza el error

> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1

El caso es que si recupero la informacion de la siguiente manera:

```
//Resultado 1
$arreglo = mysql_fetch_array ($resultado)
echo $arreglo["nombre"];
//Resultado 2
$arreglo = mysql_fetch_array ($resultado)
echo $arreglo["nombre"];
//Resultado 3
$arreglo = mysql_fetch_array ($resultado)
echo $arreglo["nombre"];
```

Me imprime los valores esperados.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Donde seleccionas tu base de datos? haces `$db_nombre="prueba";` pero no veo donde lo utilizas

Answer (score 1):

Tal como apunta @Hechi en el comentario de la pregunta, necesitas seleccionar la base de datos, `mysql` usa dos funciones distintas para configurar la conexión correctamente.

```
//...
$link     = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
$selectDb = mysql_select_db($db_nombre, $link);
//...
```

[Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/17644/5984) tienes las distintas conexiones básicas, `mysql`, `mysqli` y la clase `mysqli`.

> A modo de apunte informativo, `mysql` está [declarada como obsoleta](http://php.net/manual/es/intro.mysql.php) en nuevas versiones de php, a partir de 5.5.0 y eliminada a partir de php 7.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Eso me pasaba, al momento de conectar mi base de datos con un archivo conexion.php me decia lo mismo (`mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1`). Entonces decidí cambiar todos los `mysql` por `mysqli`.

Como resultado también cambie algunas cosas: no usaba `$db_host` sino `$host` así:

```php
<?php
global $host,$user,$password,$database;
$host='mysql.hostinger.mx';
$user='usuario_nombre';
$pass='simulacro';
$database='numero_nombre';
$conexion=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die ("conexion fallida");
mysqli_select_db($conexion,$database) or die ("Error al conectarse con la Base de Datos".mysqli_error($conexion));
?>
```

Es más por complejidad, por no perderme o dañar el código por si más adelante llego a usar alguno parecido, y luego en todos los archivos solo pondré `require('conexion.php');` y listo, conectadas todas las páginas con sólo ese código

Luego pones

```php
<? 
$query="SELECT * FROM tabla (condisionales WHERE, ASC, DESC...)";
$resultado=$conexion->query($query);
while($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){ 
    ?>RESULTADO QUE QUIERES QUE SE MUESTRE
     y finalizas con
<?}?>
```

y listo, tienes el muestreo de datos de la tabla.

Comment: Sin duda, se debe usar MySQLi, no sólo porque las funciones `mysql_*` están obsoletas, sino también para evitar el riesgo de seguridad que conllevan. De todas formas, no veo que esto esté relacionado con el error que se recibe. ¿Podrías comentar a qué se debe y cómo estás haciendo en el código para evitarlo?